# Unable to start Android emulator > 1.5

Tags: android, android-emulator, glibc

I got this trace when I tried to launch android 1.6 or 2.1. Android 1.5 is working fine. I tried to reinstall each SDK, but there is no way to get it working. I created those AVD with Eclipse plugin.

```
geo@geo-laptop:~> android/android-sdk-linux_86/tools/emulator -avd a16
*** glibc detected *** android/android-sdk-linux_86/tools/emulator: free(): invalid pointer: 0x45454545 ***
======= Backtrace: =========                                                                               
/lib/libc.so.6(+0x6df7b)[0xb748cf7b]                                                                       
/lib/libc.so.6(cfree+0xd9)[0xb7491ac9]                                                                     
android/android-sdk-linux_86/tools/emulator[0x80db20c]                                                     
android/android-sdk-linux_86/tools/emulator[0x840eb38]                                                     
======= Memory map: ========                                                                               
08048000-08246000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 5693701    /home/geo/android/android-sdk-linux_86/tools/emulator     
08246000-08249000 rw-p 001fd000 08:06 5693701    /home/geo/android/android-sdk-linux_86/tools/emulator     
08249000-08445000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                                                    
08445000-08447000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                                                                    
08447000-0874c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]                                                    
ad8e9000-ada86000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 85229580   /SYSV00000000 (deleted)                                   
ada86000-adced000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                                                    
adced000-add0d000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 84770825   /SYSV0056a4d6 (deleted)                                   
add0d000-adde4000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 22591      /usr/lib/libasound.so.2.0.0                               
adde4000-adde5000 ---p 000d7000 08:05 22591      /usr/lib/libasound.so.2.0.0                               
adde5000-adde8000 r--p 000d7000 08:05 22591      /usr/lib/libasound.so.2.0.0                               
adde8000-adde9000 rw-p 000da000 08:05 22591      /usr/lib/libasound.so.2.0.0                               
adde9000-ade09000 rw-s 00000000 00:05 3268       /dev/snd/pcmC0D0p                                         
ade09000-b3e0b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                                                    
b3e0b000-b3e0c000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0                                                                    
b3e0c000-b55cd000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                                                    
b55cd000-b6dcd000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                                                                    
b6dcd000-b6ea3000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                                                    
b6ea4000-b7205000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                                                    
b7205000-b7209000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 22491      /usr/lib/libXfixes.so.3.1.0                               
b7209000-b720a000 r--p 00003000 08:05 22491      /usr/lib/libXfixes.so.3.1.0                               
b720a000-b720b000 rw-p 00004000 08:05 22491      /usr/lib/libXfixes.so.3.1.0                               
b7212000-b7222000 rw-s 00000000 00:05 3269       /dev/snd/pcmC0D0c                                         
b7222000-b7226000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 22588      /usr/lib/alsa-lib/libasound_module_rate_speexrate.so      
b7226000-b7227000 r--p 00003000 08:05 22588      /usr/lib/alsa-lib/libasound_module_rate_speexrate.so      
b7227000-b7228000 rw-p 00004000 08:05 22588      /usr/lib/alsa-lib/libasound_module_rate_speexrate.so      
b7228000-b7229000 rw-s 81000000 00:05 3268       /dev/snd/pcmC0D0p                                         
b7229000-b722a000 r--s 80000000 00:05 3268       /dev/snd/pcmC0D0p                                         
b722a000-b722b000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 84738056   /SYSV0056a4d5 (deleted)                                   
b722b000-b7276000 r--p 00000000 08:05 85242      /var/cache/libx11/compose/l4_024_313cb605_00280cc0        
b7276000-b72b5000 r--p 00000000 08:05 20724      /usr/lib/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_CTYPE
b72b5000-b73d2000 r--p 00000000 08:05 101088     /usr/lib/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_COLLATE
b73d2000-b73d9000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 22991      /usr/lib/libXrandr.so.2.2.0
b73d9000-b73da000 r--p 00006000 08:05 22991      /usr/lib/libXrandr.so.2.2.0
b73da000-b73db000 rw-p 00007000 08:05 22991      /usr/lib/libXrandr.so.2.2.0
b73db000-b73e4000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 4146       /usr/lib/libXrender.so.1.3.0
b73e4000-b73e5000 r--p 00008000 08:05 4146       /usr/lib/libXrender.so.1.3.0
b73e5000-b73e6000 rw-p 00009000 08:05 4146       /usr/lib/libXrender.so.1.3.0
b73e6000-b73f7000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 3705       /usr/lib/libXext.so.6.4.0
b73f7000-b73f8000 r--p 00010000 08:05 3705       /usr/lib/libXext.so.6.4.0
b73f8000-b73f9000 rw-p 00011000 08:05 3705       /usr/lib/libXext.so.6.4.0
b73f9000-b73fa000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
b73fa000-b73fc000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 8573       /usr/lib/libXau.so.6.0.0
b73fc000-b73fd000 r--p 00001000 08:05 8573       /usr/lib/libXau.so.6.0.0
b73fd000-b73fe000 rw-p 00002000 08:05 8573       /usr/lib/libXau.so.6.0.0
b73fe000-b73ff000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
b73ff000-b741d000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 3862       /usr/lib/libxcb.so.1.1.0
b741d000-b741e000 r--p 0001d000 08:05 3862       /usr/lib/libxcb.so.1.1.0
b741e000-b741f000 rw-p 0001e000 08:05 3862       /usr/lib/libxcb.so.1.1.0
b741f000-b7583000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 39690      /lib/libc-2.11.1.so
b7583000-b7584000 ---p 00164000 08:05 39690      /lib/libc-2.11.1.so
b7584000-b7586000 r--p 00164000 08:05 39690      /lib/libc-2.11.1.so
b7586000-b7587000 rw-p 00166000 08:05 39690      /lib/libc-2.11.1.so
b7587000-b758a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
b758a000-b75a6000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 11519      /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
b75a6000-b75a7000 r--p 0001b000 08:05 11519      /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
b75a7000-b75a8000 rw-p 0001c000 08:05 11519      /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
b75a8000-b768b000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 85419      /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.14
b768b000-b768c000 ---p 000e3000 08:05 85419      /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.14
b768c000-b7690000 r--p 000e3000 08:05 85419      /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.14
b7690000-b7691000 rw-p 000e7000 08:05 85419      /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.14
b7691000-b7698000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
b7698000-b76c0000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 39698      /lib/libm-2.11.1.so
b76c0000-b76c1000 r--p 00027000 08:05 39698      /lib/libm-2.11.1.so
b76c1000-b76c2000 rw-p 00028000 08:05 39698      /lib/libm-2.11.1.so
b76c2000-b76d9000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 39716      /lib/libpthread-2.11.1.so
b76d9000-b76da000 r--p 00016000 08:05 39716      /lib/libpthread-2.11.1.so
b76da000-b76db000 rw-p 00017000 08:05 39716      /lib/libpthread-2.11.1.so
b76db000-b76de000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
b76de000-b76e1000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 39696      /lib/libdl-2.11.1.so
b76e1000-b76e2000 r--p 00002000 08:05 39696      /lib/libdl-2.11.1.so
b76e2000-b76e3000 rw-p 00003000 08:05 39696      /lib/libdl-2.11.1.so
b76e3000-b76eb000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 39720      /lib/librt-2.11.1.so
b76eb000-b76ec000 r--p 00007000 08:05 39720      /lib/librt-2.11.1.so
b76ec000-b76ed000 rw-p 00008000 08:05 39720      /lib/librt-2.11.1.so
b76ed000-b76ef000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 39725      /lib/libutil-2.11.1.so
b76ef000-b76f0000 r--p 00001000 08:05 39725      /lib/libutil-2.11.1.so
b76f0000-b76f1000 rw-p 00002000 08:05 39725      /lib/libutil-2.11.1.so
b76f1000-b7828000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 4550       /usr/lib/libX11.so.6.3.0
b7828000-b7829000 r--p 00136000 08:05 4550       /usr/lib/libX11.so.6.3.0
b7829000-b782c000 rw-p 00137000 08:05 4550       /usr/lib/libX11.so.6.3.0
b782c000-b782d000 rw-s 81000000 00:05 3269       /dev/snd/pcmC0D0c
b782d000-b782e000 r--s 80000000 00:05 3269       /dev/snd/pcmC0D0c
b782e000-b782f000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 82771979   /SYSV0056a4d7 (deleted)
b782f000-b7839000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 22208      /usr/lib/libXcursor.so.1.0.2
b7839000-b783a000 r--p 00009000 08:05 22208      /usr/lib/libXcursor.so.1.0.2
b783a000-b783b000 rw-p 0000a000 08:05 22208      /usr/lib/libXcursor.so.1.0.2
b783b000-b783c000 r--p 00000000 08:05 20194      /usr/lib/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_NUMERIC
b783c000-b783d000 r--p 00000000 08:05 100190     /usr/lib/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_TIME
b783d000-b783e000 r--p 00000000 08:05 100189     /usr/lib/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_MONETARY[1]    24082 abort      android/android-sdk-linux_86/tools/emulator -avd a16
```

Comment: what linux flavor and SO version are you  using?

Comment: OpenSuSE 11.2
Linux geo-laptop 2.6.31.12-0.2-default #1 SMP 2010-03-16 21:25:39 +0100 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

Comment: Sounds like the problem I'm having. Emulators > 1.5 just hang and never start fully on windows either

Answer (score 0):

```
 free(): invalid pointer: 0x45454545 ***
```

This looks like memory corruption, trying to free a pointer, which was rewriten by AAAAA string.  This address is usual when trying to overflow some buffer.

Seems to be an error in the emulator.